# I want to pass values in (entry) to function in python, but i have some error

Tags: python, lambda

```
b = Button(root3,text="ADD",command=lambda: update_file(str(ent1.get()),str(ent3.get()),str(ent2.get())))
```

I have this is error :

```
File "C:/Users/khaled/PycharmProjects/projectAI/fathy1.py", line 29, in <lambda>
b = Button(root3,text="ADD",fg="white",bg="blue",width=10,command=lambda: update_file(str(ent1.get()),str(ent3.get()),str(ent2.get())))
```

Comment: What about not using a lambda but go for a non-anonimized function?

Comment: Is something else passing the arguments fg="white" and bg="blue". I'm not super familiar with this module, but I didn't see that in your original code, and was wondering where it came from.

Comment: code  :

https://1drv.ms/t/s!Aps2wSUDrkfag2nW-US1LXpZ7r4n

Answer (score 0):

**Define a function and give command name as that function name**

```
def myFun():
    update_file(str(ent1.get()),str(ent3.get()),str(ent2.get()))

b = Button(root3,text="ADD",command=myFun)
```

Comment: (ent1 & ent2 & ent3) are local not global to access them in function , and if i try to make them global some errors happen